# How to use git bash in windows for cloning an Android project

Tags: android, git, android-source, ime

I want to create an IME for android in arabic language.
I needed some reference and found this :
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/res

Now I wanted to clone one of the directory trees onto my system as it was said there.

I installed git on windows and I got a 'git bash' icon. I opened it , what it asked and got this error :

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Now I am clueless.
How should I download that source?

Comment: What command did you run, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact line you need is

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME
```